# TypeScript mapped type with required scalar properties and optional objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I want a TypeScript generic type that can modify another type such that any scalar properties (strings, numbers, booleans etc.) remain required, but object types become optional.

For example with this `User` type, I would want `name` and `age` to be required, but `address` to be optional.

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: {
    street: string;
    postcode: string;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing out this question, I worked out the answer. Isn't StackOverflow great!

```
type ScalarTypes = string | number | boolean | Date;
type OptionalObjects<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends ScalarTypes ? P : never]: T[P];
} & {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends ScalarTypes ? never : P]?: T[P];
};

// this is valid
const partialUser: OptionalObjects<User> = {
  name: "Me",
  age: 12,
};

// this is valid
const fullUser: OptionalObjects<User> = {
  name: "Me",
  age: 12,
  address: {
    street: "My Street",
    postcode: "AB123",
  },
};

// @ts-expect-error this is not allowed because name and age are missing
const emptyUser: OptionalObjects<User> = {};
```